# Error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'full_name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

I have defined a column 'full_name' on staffs table which is also set to be not null. When I run the below test(patient_test.rb)  I get the below given terminal output. Since I am not running the test against the staff table I do not understand why I get this error.

Can anyone suggest why I keep getting this error when I am not even running the test on that particular model.

Schema for staffs tables

```
create_table "staffs", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "full_name",   null: false
    t.string   "first_name",  null: false
    t.string   "middle_name"
    t.string   "last_name",   null: false
    t.boolean  "gender",      null: false
    t.string   "telephone",   null: false
    t.string   "email",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

Test file (patient_test.rb)

```
require 'test_helper'

class PatientTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

test "should not save user without patient" do
  patient = Patient.new
  assert_not user.save
end

end
```

Terminal Output.

```
rake test
(in /home/user/Rubymine/project1)
Run options: --seed 51365

# Running:

E

Error:
PatientTest#test_should_not_save_user_without_patient:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'full_name' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `staffs` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`) VALUES ('2017-03-28 08:45:58', '2017-03-28 08:45:58', 980190962)



bin/rails test test/models/patient_test.rb:9



Finished in 0.112169s, 8.9151 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Furthermore my staff.rb files only have the relationships and scopes (if any) in them.

Staff.rb File

```
class Staff < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :user
  has_many :time_slots

  validates_presence_of :full_name
end
```

Contents at /fixtures/staffs.yml

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

# This model initially had no columns defined. If you add columns to the
# model remove the '{}' from the fixture names and add the columns immediately
# below each fixture, per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

Comment: Are there any fixtures the test framework is trying to create? If you're using Minitest they are in `test/fixtures`

Comment: @Iceman I posted the corresponding file contents for the staff. plaease check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have declared null false condition of most of the columns on staffs table. Rails load all fixtures before running each test run, so when the fixture 'staffs.yml' is hit, rails immediately raise error because the fixture has two records (one and two) that do not have values required by your database.

You basically have 3 options:

1. Remove the file of the fixture: staffs.yml
2. Commented (giving the '#' notation in front of all lines on that fixture
3. Add the required columns with values for staff one and two

Comment: Thankyou!! You found the solution!

For future visitors, this is the solution to the error. I up voted this answer but sadly my up vote is not yet visible.